# Which Python module to use for Memcached?

Tags: python, caching, memcached

I am implementing caching for my Python application and I want to use memcached. Which module do you suggest me to use? There are so many that I don't know which one to choose.

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [python-memcached](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/) and there's some good advice on usage in the source code header, referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868690/good-examples-of-python-memcache-memcached-being-used-in-python/868731#868731).

Use the third parameter to set the expiry.

From bundled `memcached.html` help file:

```
set(self, key, val, time=0, min_compress_len=0)
```

so

```
mc.set(key, val, time)
```

More info and exmaples [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ha-memcached-interfaces-python.html)

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how to make a key expire? The examples on that page, just set the keys, but how to make them expire after, let's say 444 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

I use cmemcache, which is more performant (but no more mantained). As its developer suggest, you can switch to http://code.google.com/p/python-libmemcached.

Comment: I am confused now -- Isn't it the same?

Answer (score 2):

I use [python-memcache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/) because:

1. You can run in locally
2. It is embedded in [Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
3. Simple to use

from memcached.py header:

```
    import memcache

    mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)

    mc.set("some_key", "Some value")
    value = mc.get("some_key")

    mc.set("another_key", 3)
    mc.delete("another_key")

    mc.set("key", "1")   # note that the key used for incr/decr must be a string.
    mc.incr("key")
    mc.decr("key")
```

or use as part of Django framework: ([details here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/))

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)
>>> cache.get('my_key')
'hello, world!'
```